# Calculate some data and draw corresponding image in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got a question with my ASP.NET page.
On the page I have a form with some textboxes and a submit button. How can I do the following:

1. Get data from the textboxes
2. Calculate some values
3. Draw and place an image after the form using these values.

Third step - is the problem for me.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I use C# as code behind language.

Comment: http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/generating-asp-net-images-fly, this describes what your are looking for. I generally love the sitepoint articles ^^

Comment: And how can I move image after the form?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, basically the idea behin this is that the [image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) class can [write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah.aspx) to a [stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx).
What you do is you write the image to the [Response.OutputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream.aspx).

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(x,y);
bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream);
```

One problem with this, is that a browser still thinks it's recieving HTML, you can change this by changing the ContentType of you're response:

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpg"; //Or any other content-type like image/png etc...
```

That way you're page will return an image instead of html.

In your case, what you probably want to do is create a seperate aspx page, that will return the image based on the data you'll pass to it. That way you can embed it in your website like:

```
<img src="Image.aspx" />
```

You can pass the data to it by storing it in a Session or by passing it in the querystring.

Comment: >You can pass the data to it by storing it in a Session or by passing it in the querystring - Can you show me an example of this?